# Why is the MYSQLi not updating the DB record but giving success message

Tags: php, mysqli

I have cleaned my code a little to have the following as my form. But I'm having trouble sending the data and Updating from the new update.php. The form works ok retrieving the data and displaying it. But on submission I get the ok update message but the record isn't changed in the database any ideas. 
index.php

```
<?php
  include 'connectdb.php';
  // include 'query.php';

  $sql = "SELECT id, WeightorMeasure FROM weightsmeasures";
  $result = $conn->query($sql)       
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<form action=\"update.php\"method=\"post\">";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value = ".$row["id"].">";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"WeightorMeasure\" value = ".$row["WeightorMeasure"] .">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\" Submit \" name=\"Update\">";
    }
        echo "</form>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }  
       $conn->close();
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
  include 'connectdb.php';
  $wm = $_POST['id'];
  $id = $_POST['WeightorMeasure'];
  $sql = "UPDATE weightsmeasures SET WeightorMeasure='$wm' WHERE id='$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Have changed to Below and now get this error.
Error updating record: Unknown column 'sdada' in 'field list'. So it looks like its trying to use the form value $wm as a column header in the table rather than the input value.

```
$wm = $_POST['WeightorMeasure'];
$id = $_POST['id'];


$sql = "UPDATE weightsmeasures SET WeightorMeasure=$wm WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: `value attribute` should be enclosed by `single quotes` or `double quotes` . since value is not have any space between string means. it will okay if have any space between string means first part of string only consider as a value other string or ignored .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 $wm = $_POST['id'];
 $id = $_POST['WeightorMeasure'];
```

Maybe you have these the wrong way round? :D

```
 $wm = $_POST['WeightorMeasure'];
 $id = $_POST['id'];
```

By the way your query is vuln to MySQL injection, please consider using prepared statements

Answer (score 3):

You realize that you switched your ID and WeightOrMeasure in the variable assignments from your $_POST data?
This results in an update query that can't find the ID but does not run into a problem. Thus telling you that the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

I figure out following possible problem in your code.

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //should be $conn->query($sql);
```

and this line

```
 $wm = $_POST['id']; //$_POST['WeightorMeasure'];
  $id = $_POST['WeightorMeasure'];//$_POST['id'];
```

the order is wrong.  I hope you already have $conn object created in dpconnect.php file.

Comment: mysqli_query is correct usage. He's using procedural rather than objects.

Comment: You are right however, he has used $conn object for fetching the data form database, and include same connection file in update.php file I  think he should use objects.

Comment: @WillParky93 nothing good to spot here. he could use whatever style he wishes, it is no problem whatsoever. PHP is known for the vast amount of wild superstitions and this answer is based on one of them. Do not help spreading it further, mark it down

Answer (score -1):

Ok found the problem was a mixture of the above having $_POST["WeightorMeasure"]; and $_POST["id"]; mixed up but the most important factor was that the table I was posting from contained Multiple Rows and on _POST to update.php it didn't know what to do with all the different rows as the SQL was only dealing with one row. Once I sent single rows through the post it worked fine. Now to learn and add prepared statements as suggested.

update.php

```
 <?php
       include 'connectdb.php';
       $wm = $_POST["WeightorMeasure"];
       $id = $_POST["id"];

        echo $wm . "<br>";
        echo $id . "<br"; 

        $sql = "UPDATE weightsmeasures SET WeightorMeasure=\"$wm\", id= 
         $idWHERE id= $id";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Manual single entry.
index.php

```
<?php
   include 'connectdb.php';
   // include 'query.php';

   $sql = "SELECT id, WeightorMeasure FROM weightsmeasures WHERE id=11";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

           // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<form action=\"update.php\"method=\"post\">";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value = ".$row["id"].">";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"WeightorMeasure\" value = ".$row["WeightorMeasure"].">";
          echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\" Submit \" name=\"Update\">";
           }         
              echo "</form>";
             } else {
              echo "0 results";
             }  
       $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php may be a good place to start